# How to get only some columns from dataframe based on list items?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, drop

I have a list named `options=['pm1','pm10']` and a dataframe which contains more columns. I would like to get from the dataframe only the ds, y, pm1 and pm10 options, based on the options list.
The wanted result:

```
df=df[['ds', 'y', 'pm1', 'pm10']]
```

But how could I achieve the same result by using the pm1 and pm10 taken from the list?
I tried:

```
df=df[['ds', 'y',options]]
```

But this triggers the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: you can also use `df[['ds', 'y']+options]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
df=df[['ds', 'y',*options]]
```

If you'd like to know why that works. It's because in this setting * isn't a multiplication, but the [iterable unpacking operator](https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use * in front of variables to unpack them.

Try: `df[['d', 'y', *options]]` and see if that works.